# How can I send by text a message from Gmail?

Tags: gmail, sms

I want to forward a Gmail message from my daughter to text so I can send it out by SMS on my phone.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15988/can-i-send-and-receive-text-messages-online

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Voice/Text service too, if you're in the US that would be free for you.

Go to [Google Voice](https://www.google.com/voice) website, verify your phone number and get a Google number, then you can easily forward messages from your Gmail account to any phone.

It's very easy!

Answer (score 1):

What's your carrier? Most have an email-to-SMS bridge. Verizon Wireless, for instance, uses {phonenumber}@vtext.com (*e.g.*, 2128675309@vtext.com).

[Here's a list for carriers in the U.S.](http://hacknmod.com/hack/email-to-text-messages-for-att-verizon-t-mobile-sprint-virgin-more/) but I don't know how up-to-date it is.

Further, many carriers have web forms to allow sending arbitrary text to any customer, so you could just copy-paste the message in the form. Verizon Wireless's is at http://www.vtext.com/. Check your carrier's website.

Either way, this isn't a Gmail-specific question; that just happens to be the email service being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a free application : http://airdroid.com/
With this application you can access all your messages (and a lot more) from your PC via wifi. So you can copy/past your gmail message.

You can find this application on google play here : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid

Comment: Asker did not mention that he was using an Android, or even any smartphone.